# Taskqueue HTTP 1.1 404 error Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-tasks

We are executing taskqueue. Based on documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-push-queues)  , we have created a new queue called "generate-reports". Our queue.yaml looks like this.

```
- name: generate-reports
  target: v2.task-module
  rate: 5/s
  max_concurrent_requests: 10
  bucket_size: 40
```

We check the google cloud console and can verify that the "generate-reports" queue is active.

We are then placing a task in this queue using this.

```
class scheduledownloadreport(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    # Call the report to get the elements
    ScheduleReportDownload_cloudapi_obj = schedulereportdownload_cloudapi.ScheduleReportDownload_cloudapi()
    data_sent_obj = ScheduleReportDownload_cloudapi_obj.schedule_download(
                    download_obj)



class schedulereportdownload_cloudapi():     

    taskqueue.Queue(name='generate-reports')            
        task = taskqueue.add(
            url='/schedulebackendtasktocreatereport',
            target='worker',
            queue_name = 'generate-reports',
            params={
                "task_data"     : task_data
            })
```

We also tried this.

```
taskqueue.Queue(name='generate-reports')            
        task = taskqueue.add(
            url='/worker/schedulebackendtasktocreatereport',
            target='worker',
            queue_name = 'generate-reports',
            params={
                "task_data"     : task_data
            })
```

In both instances we are getting the following error -

```
"POST /schedulebackendtasktocreatereport HTTP/1.1" 404 113 https://MY-PROJECT-NAME/schedulereportdownload
```

If we use just (without the queue_name parameter)

```
    taskqueue.Queue(name='generate-reports')            
        task = taskqueue.add(
            url='/schedulebackendtasktocreatereport',
            target='worker',
            params={
                "task_data"     : task_data
            })
```

the tasks work like a charm. they get queued into the default queue.

UPDATED WITH SOLUTION

```
- name: generate-reports
  target: worker
  rate: 5/s
  max_concurrent_requests: 10
  bucket_size: 40
```

Comment: Why does your queue.yaml have `target: v2.task-module` but your call to `taskqueue.Queue` have `target='worker'`

Comment: Found this by trial and error. Changed it to  ***target: worker*** and it worked. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Jacktileman Would be great if you can post the solution as an answer, in order to get more visibility for other users with the same issue! Thanks :)

Comment: @eespinola - done.

Comment: @Jacktileman Thanks for updating your post, but the best way would be to post as a new answer, so other users can see that this post has already an answer accepted.
You can do it and accept your own answer, or either I can do it as [community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the target name to "worker" in queue.yaml and it worked.

```
- name: generate-reports
  target: worker
  rate: 5/s
  max_concurrent_requests: 10
  bucket_size: 40
```